# Spark SaveMode.append while Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is a Streaming job dequeue data from Eventhub.

I am using the following code to partition my Dataframe by time and output as json
Sometime there could be a late records coming in, I want to add that record to the file where it belongs, so I use the following code.

```
    df.write.partitionBy("Time")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .json(output)
```

After I check the streaming Statistics per stages, this step is by far the slowest step of all. I am wondering is there an alternative way that can perform the same but more efficient?

Every batch of data is about 50gb.

Thanks

Comment: What other operations are you doing on this? Writing JSON can take a while. Are there any predicate filters you are also doing while writing this data?